# How to set default selection in Vue

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuejs2

I can't seem to set default select option, as soon as I had `v-model` the default selection does not work anymore

Working:

```
<select class="uk-select uk-form-width-large" style="float: right">
        <option hidden>Select Bank</option>
        <option v-for="bank in bank_list" v-bind:value="bank">
            {{ bank.bank_name }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Not working:

```
<select class="uk-select uk-form-width-large" style="float: right" v-model="bank_selected">
    <option hidden>Select Bank</option>
    <option v-for="bank in bank_list" v-bind:value="bank">
        {{ bank.bank_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Since setting default option works without `v-model` I try to use `@onChange` but cant figure out how to pass selected bank because the bank loop is in `<options>` not in `<select>` tag

```
<select class="uk-select uk-form-width-large" style="float: right" @onChange="selectOnChange">
    <option hidden>Select Bank</option>
    <option v-for="bank in bank_list" v-bind:value="bank">
        {{ bank.bank_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Data and Methods:

```
data() {
    return {
        bank_list: [...],
        bank_selected: {}, // empty by default
    }
},
methods: {
    selectOnChange(event) {
        console.log("onChange....", event);
        // logs event but cannot get value in event.target.value 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, Your data value for **bank_selected** by default is an empty object ( **{}** ) so make your default option value have an empty object too.

```
<option :value="{}" hidden>Select Bank</option>
```

> Dont forget the colon ( : )  before value="" >>> :value="{}"

Answer (score 1):

For the structure without `v-model`:

The "change event" of a **SELECT**  is `@change`, try this:

**HTML**

```
<select class="uk-select uk-form-width-large" style="float: right" @change="selectOnChange">
    <option hidden>Select Bank</option>
    <option v-for="bank in bank_list" :value="bank">
        {{ bank.bank_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

With the event you should be able to obtain the selected element:

**JS**

```
methods: {
    selectOnChange(event) {
        console.log(event.srcElement.value)
    }
}
```